# Chrome Print - Save as PDF - Print to One Page

Tags: google-chrome, print-to-pdf

**When printing via "Save as PDF" in Chrome, how can I make the size of the page fit the webpage dimensions?**

The page I'm trying to generate a PDF from has a bunch of graphs on it, and I don't plan on printing it to paper - I'd just like to generate a presentable document. But, when I go to print it as a PDF, my graphs keep getting diced up from all the pages. I'd like to simply print everything on one page. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you adjusted the layout settings and Advanced settings? There are settings for the layout, paper size, margins, and scaling.

Comment: I'm offered a few sizes - A0 - A5, Legal, and Tabloid - but none of these work, as the page is way too long. I'm also ideally looking for a solution where I don't have to guess the *exact* length of the page, as I need to print a series of web pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, I've found a Chrome extension that works for what I'm doing. It allows me to snapshot the entire page, and then save it as a PDF or image. The only disadvantage of this method is that the page (even when a PDF) is, as a whole, an image. Thus the text is not selectable or vector scalable.

Here's the extension if it helps anyone else:
[Take Webpage Screenshots Entirely - FireShot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/take-webpage-screenshots/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg)

Answer (score 8):

> NOTICE: THIS APPROACH IS SEMI DEPRECATED

Chrome is <strike>fairly</strike> REALLY impressive with its ability to allow customization in the print section for page sizes.

As such, you can customize your print size. This really saved me when having to print a 32" by 80" web page to pdf.

Here are the directions (remember, we are modifying the front end of the page, so this is a little techy and involves some HTML modification)

1. Ctrl + p to open the print dialog
2. Click on "More Settings" to expand the lower section
3. Right Click on the "Paper Size" dropdown and click "Inspect"
   (note: this will open chrome's Dev tools)
4. In Dev tools, `<select class="md-select">...</select>` will be highlighted, click the arrow next to it to expand that section.
5. Once expanded, the first option will be:
   `<option value="{&quot;height_microns&quot;:1189000,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;ISO_A0&quot;,&quot;width_microns&quot;:841000,&quot;custom_display_name&quot;:&quot;A0&quot;}">A0</option>`
6. Right click on that, and then select "Edit as HTML". A text editing section will open up, with the previous option's text all highlighted.

At this point, all you need to do is insert a custom option into this list after the existing one. This means pasting in your own. Unfortunately I cannot build a tool to make the snippet for you to paste as superuser doesn't allow stacksnippets.

There are only a few values you need to modify. I have changed the names to CUSTOM here below.

You will notice that in the text below, there is HHHHHHHHHH and WWWWWWWWWW. These must be manually changed to the micron values associated with your desired dimensions. This website provides a nice free micron calculator: https://www.calculateme.com/length/inches/to-microns/

For my height it was: 80 Inches =
2,032,000 Microns, so for the HHHHHHHHHH I replaced that with 2032000

For my width it was 32 Inches =
812,800 Microns, so for the WWWWWWWWWW I replaced that with 812800

Please find your own associated values and do the same with the below text.

```
<option value="{&quot;height_microns&quot;:HHHHHHHHHH,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;ISO_CUSTOM&quot;,&quot;width_microns&quot;:WWWWWWWWWW,&quot;custom_display_name&quot;:&quot;CUSTOM&quot;}">CUSTOM</option>
```

Once that text is ready to go, place it directly after the section in the "Edit as HTML" text editor. Once done, click anywhere outside of the text editing area to cause the changes to render.

At this point, you can click on the dropdown menu, see your CUSTOM option, and select it.

I know this sounds arduous, however, it is really pretty straightforward, and if you are making a pdf from something really custom, it should save you quite a lot of time.

---

*serious updates*

At some point, it would appear that the print preview from Google chrome updated to be more test driven. As a result, adding a custom value violates a test condition and nothing happens. This approach no longer works as shown.

The requirement here is to literally intercept the values using the debugger in order to bypass the prevention of the test assertions. Sorry, but that is too in depth to write here. As well, I am concerned that there is a possibility that by publishing a current working fix it will then subsequently be protected against for some reason or another.

Dear Google, if you are indeed looking at these posts, perhaps just allow a custom micron option? It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There was a breaking change that google implemented which seems to disallows this approach at the moment =/ Working on a fix.

Comment: Message me the details if you wouldn't mind. I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: This dialog no longer shows "More Settings" (see bug: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/70209820/print-as-pdf-more-settings), but this answer was still useful for me in picking another pre-defined paper size . Once I opened dev console, I searched for "Paper Size", found the `option` corresponding to the size I want, edited it as html and added `selected` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Modern and only solution:

Inject the following CSS anywhere in the page source *(or a CSS file used by the page itself)* and change the dimensions to any value you prefer.

```css
@page {
    size: 4.0in 25.5in; /* <- You can change these dimensions */
    margin: 0;
}
```

Now try the "Save as PDF" option and you'll see that the pages will be in those dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround, using an online tool to post-process your chrome generated PDF (with a 128mb total size limit for upload as of now). However, you cannot do much about the page width of the final result, which, at most, can be set to the height or width of the page-size options already available in Chrome's Print Dialog. Also you may not be able to save the Header & Footer (read the note at the end).

Please note that even though the shapes/images of the document and it's background graphics (if you include them) may look intact as one single shape or an image, it may actually be two or more pieces of the original that were broken at the page borders as seen in your Chrome print-dialog. This should not be a problem at all as long as you want to view your PDF and do not intend to edit it.

Here's what you can do:

1. Ctrl+P (Print Dialog) > Select Printer: 'Save As PDF'
2. Choose Layout: Portrait (Default) or Landscape <-- Width of the final result depends on this. For example, in case you select the 'A4' paper size from the page size option (mentioned in below step no. 4) which is a 8.27in(210mm) x 11.69in(297mm) paper size, then it will output a PDF  with 8.27in(210mm) width if you selected Portrait or, 11.69in(297mm) width if you selected Landscape.
3. Click(Expand) to show 'More Settings'
4. Select the appropriate 'Paper size' to go with the Page layout you selected above.
5. Margins: set to 'None' <-- This will also remove Page Header & Footer.
6. Scale: Default (which is same as the 'Custom' option set to 100)
7. Tick the 'Background Graphics' checkbox if you want to keep them, otherwise uncheck it.
8. Save your PDF
9. Now go to https://avepdf.com/convert-to-one-page-pdf
10. Select 'Choose file' and select the above PDF from your device.
11. After the combine process completes, click on the link below with your PDF filename, your desired 1-page PDF file will be downloaded.

Note: If you plan to keep the header/footer then you cannot set the margins to NONE. In that case, after setting the margins from the available options, tick the 'Headers and Footers' checkbox that will show up right above the 'Background Graphics' option. However, now the page margins and the header-footers will show up in between all the pages of the multi-page PDF (saved from Chrome) which will be combined (as one page below the other) in your final single-page PDF.

Answer (score -3):

Chrome has a standard but small set of tools for page layout in the Print dialog. These are right below where you select the print, and so are not hard to miss.

[image]

There is Layout, where you can choose between Portrait and Landscape.

There is Paper size, where you can select between various standard sizes.

There is Margins, where you can adjust the unprinted margins of the page.

There is Scale, which will perhaps be the most helpful for this.

And there are additional options for including/excluding Headers/Footers and Background Graphics.

Printing web pages is an inexact art because much of page design is actually explicitly defined in the page code, and that is not optimized for print layout. These explicitly-define page layout codes conflict with the print layout options you may be familiar with from word processing or other applications, where the program can exert greater control over the layout of the document.

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear. I don't want to *scale* the content - otherwise I get tons of unwanted whitespace, and an extreme amount for long pages. I want to make the page size fit the content.

Comment: These are the options available to you. Take them or leave them.

Comment: When I select save to PDF, even most of these options disappear including paper size and orientation.  If I'm printing to a real printer I do get those options, but not when saving to pdf.